# Update prices before loading shop / product list in WooCommerce

Tags: mysql, woocommerce, hook

I am currently developing a website for a trade / wholesale company who offer their clients different discounts (there are roughly 30 discount groups).

I am using wordpress / woocommerce.

I have access to each customers price list through a webservice which I have successfully integrated.

I am currently getting the price and updating woocommerce using the hook **'woocommerce_before_shop_loop'**.

The issue I am having is that if all the current prices in woocommerce are set to say $1.00 but the price the current customer pays is $2.00 the first time the page loads it says  $1.00 until its reloaded.

I understand that its because the query is obviously performed before both my script runs and the page loads.

```
function t31_before_shop_list_call() {
    if ( is_user_logged_in()) {
        $Conn = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);


        $itemCodesArray = array(); // WILL CONTAIN ARRAY OF SKU's FOR WS

        while (have_posts()) : the_post();
            global $product;

            if( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ){

                $sku = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_sku', true );
                array_push($itemCodesArray, $sku);

            } elseif( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ){

                $child_ids = $product->get_children();
                foreach ($child_ids as $child_id) {
                    $sku = get_post_meta( $child_id, '_sku', true );
                    array_push($itemCodesArray, $sku);

                }

            }

        endwhile; 

        ... RUN WEBSERVICE THAT GETS CLIENTS PRICES FOR THE 

        ... RUN THROUGH EACH PRODUCT RETURNED IN WEBSERVICE AND EXEC FOLLOWING UPDATE


       UPDATE wp_postmeta
       SET meta_value = " . $GDUSproduct_price . "
       WHERE post_id = " . $GDUSproduct_id . "
       AND meta_key = '_regular_price';";


        DELETE
        FROM `wp_options`
        WHERE (`option_name` LIKE '_transient_wc_var_prices_%'
        OR  option_name` LIKE '_transient_timeout_wc_var_prices_%')";

    }

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 't31_before_shop_list_call', 15 );
```

Is there a hook I can use that executes before the query is performed or is there a way to re query before the html is displayed.?